# How to avoid global variables in Fortran 90 or higher?

Tags: design-patterns, global-variables, fortran, fortran90

I have a fortran library to which I must pass a function with a very specific format. The library then is doing some operation on my function. The function is written by a user (like me) and the library is given for granted.

Unfortunately to compute my function I need some values (some of them could be initialized once and for all in the main) and I would like to avoid the use of `common` or `save`.

I read I could use a singleton pattern but I am not very expert in template and on top of that some people criticize its use. So, 
how can I pass my variable inside the function even if I cannot have it in the arguments of my function?

Comment: Could you tell us, which library you want to use? If it is available to everyone, we could experiment ;)

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Fortran-Practice-Arjen-Markus/dp/1107603471 shows how to tackle this problem in FORTRAN77, in Fortran 90/95, 2003 and 2008 (*ie* in 4 ways).  I mention this simply to plug what I think is the best currently-available post-introductory Fortran book.

Comment: @ Stefan; It is a custom routine but you can think of something like f(x) thet inside needs a value "g"

Comment: I will have a look at Markus book but, I do not really understand how to achieve what I said in FORTRAN 77 without using common. Could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a Fortran `MODULE`, you can have your function use some variables not defined in the main program:

```
MODULE mymod
   REAL :: x = 1.35
   INTEGER :: y = 16

 CONTAINS
   FUNCTION results(a,b)
      REAL :: a, results
      INTEGER :: b
      results = a*x+real(b+y)
   END FUNCTION results

END MODULE mymod

PROGRAM extrn_func
   USE mymod, ONLY: results
   PRINT *,results(1.0, 3)
END PROGRAM extrn_func
```

Though, this method requires you to be able to add the `USE mymod` statement to the main program.

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing, anyway I declared the value private and I added a function that allows the initialization and that checks a logical private variable inside the module to allow one and only one initialization. This should prevent accidental re-initialization. Is this solution potentially thread-unsafe?