# How to avoid declaring and setting the value of a variable in each subroutine?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

How to avoid repeated declaration of a variable that has a constant value in subroutines?

For example:

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer :: n
  integer :: time

  print*, "enter n" ! this will be a constant value for the whole program
  call Calcul(time)
  print*, time  
end program

subroutine Calcul(Time)
  implicit none

  integer :: time 

  ! i don't want to declare the constant n again and again because some times the subroutines have a lot of variables.  
  time = n*2 
end subroutine
```

Sometimes there are a lot of constants that are defined by the user and I will make a lot of subroutines that use those constants, so I want to stock them and and use them without redefining them again and again.

Comment: You have to use modules. Also, do not call `n` a constant. It is a variable. You are changing it in the `read` statement.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42024559/using-global-variables-in-fortran and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040118/how-to-avoid-global-variables-in-fortran-90-or-higher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240510/how-do-you-use-fortran-90-module-data and others (possible duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For global variables use modules (old FORTRAN used common blocks, but they are obsolete):

```
module globals
  implicit none

  integer :: n

contains

  subroutine read_globals()    !you must call this subroutine at program start

    print*, "enter n" ! this will be a constant value for the whole program
    read *, n
  end subroutine
end module

!this subroutine should be better in a module too !!!
subroutine Calcul(Time)
  use globals !n comes from here
  implicit none

  integer :: time 
  time = n*2
end subroutine

program test
  use globals ! n comes from here if needed
  implicit none

  integer :: time

  call read_globals()

  call Calcul(time)

  print*, time
end program
```

There are many questions and answers explaining how to use Fortran modules properly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks that works very well and easy, is there another way without using modules?

Comment: Yes, with common blocks. I don't recommend them at all. Modern Fortran is all about modules so you should learn to use them as much as possible.

Comment: In simple cases you can also make the subroutine to be internal to the program (put it between `contains` and `end program`.

Comment: The best solution I think is using module, thank you for your help!!